# Definition of positive definite function

Tags: functions, stability-theory

I'm trying to understand a definition of a positive definite function I found in a book on Lyapunov stability

> Definition: A continuous function $W(x)$ is said to be a positive definite function if $W(0) = 0$, and $W(x) > 0$ in $R^n$ and there exists some $r > 0$ such that
>
> $\underset{||{x}|| > r }{\text{inf}} (W(x) > 0)$

What does the last condition exactly mean? I don't fully understand the infimum but I usually think of it as a minimum value.

Later an example is given of a positive definite function, e.g. $x^2$. But $x^2/(1+x^4)$ is said not to be positive definite? How can I deduce this from the definition? Does it have to do with the fact that the function doesn't go to infinity as $x$ goes to infinity?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty} x^2/(1+x^4)=0$, and $\inf_{||x||>r} W(x) = 0$

Comment: Thanks, I understand this example now but I'm still not sure if I understand the statement $$\underset{||{x}|| > r }{\text{inf}} (W(x) > 0)$$ For the smallest $||x|| > r$ the function $W(x)$ is larger than zero?

Comment: The last condition is that the smallest value of $W$ outside any ball (of radius $r$) is strictly positive. It means exactly that the function cannot be close to zero anywhere else but zero. Lyapunov function is kind of "distance" to the origin, so that if $W(x(t))\to 0$ we can conclude that $x(t)\to 0$.

Comment: Ok but doesn't the $W(x) > 0$ already tell me that?

Comment: Nope, as you see in the example: $W(x)\to 0$ when $x\to\infty$ too.

Comment: Thanks, the ball part made it more clear!